# General WordPress question

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a project that i would like to complete in Wordpress.
Basically, the story is that I have 8 boxes on my page that would each be enclosed in their own div.
I want to have a form on another page that a user can fill out and they would get to choose a box in which to  put images or text into.  If a box is taken, they can’t choose that one and must choose another.
What would be the best approach for this?  I was thinking something like a CSS gallery type theme but how would I go about letting the user choose which box?
Any ideas and nudges in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify who "the user" is in this case? The admin? A number of registered users?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in Drupal, or straight php. I think wordpress is going to be an impediment here rather than a boon. I would make each box a drupal block or node and use the standard form, to allow users to trigger editing that box. Then use CCK in control content like pictures and text and the way they display. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Pekka, a user would need to register before adding their content.  Registration is open to everybody, it wouldn’t be the admin adding the content.

@Fresheyeball, I had used drupal a couple years back for another project and loved the way that it worked but I’m not sure I would want to go through the learning curve again.  Wordpress is a much preferred option simply because that is what I am used to and I am comfortable with hacking into a wordpress theme.

Comment: @user537137 the problem is, using posts to fill the boxes means that users will have to be admins to access the rooted editing form in WP. Otherwise you will have to do more than hack the theme, you will have to write a custom form and form handler that allows non-admins to edit the posts. Then you will have to detect if the user is registered ect. Drupal would handle all of this native, and while I respect that WP is what you are used to; avoiding the 'learning curve' needed for the best solution is the wrong mentality. WP is just not right for all instances.

Comment: All of that is fine to do, I have set up events web sites before where users can register and create their own posts, it is just the choosing of their own location that I am stuck on.

Comment: I might be able to give each box its own category and allow the user to choose which ‘category’ to post in?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this going anywhere is more or less completely bypassing Wordpress. So you use Wordpress only to render the theme, but the form action goes straight to PHP.

This way you're free to parse the form posts and store the uploaded images somewhere.

You could try to shoehorn everything into a Wordpress comment, but I don't think attaching files would work. So your best bet is to just have the form action point to a PHP file and handle everything manually.

It should be easy enough to query a custom table in the database using your theme's functions.php and $wpdb.